# PHP regular expression split

Tags: php, regex

I will make this quick and simple

I have a query and I want to split it so that it returns an array with words after the : symbol. This is what I have so far and it does as expected but returns the whole string before the matched needle. I just want the array to contain words after the : symbol.

```
<?php  $arr = preg_split('/[:]/', $query, 0); 

   print_r($arr);

 ?>
```

This returns

```
    Array
(
    [0] => SELECT user_name FROM test WHERE user_name = 
    [1] => user_name
)
```

using this query

"SELECT user_name FROM test WHERE user_name = :user_name"

thanks for any help

Comment: can you please fix up your examples so they're understandable. thanks.

Comment: [What is this for](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)? What, exactly, is the desired result for the example? Also, please provide more examples of input & desired results.

Comment: Um, you're looking for `print_r($arr[1])`?

Comment: result is fine, use `$arr[1]`.

Comment: The purpose of this is to get the bind parameters keywords, then store them in an array and using a for loop bindParam using the values from the array

Comment: I tested the code, in my answer, it works :)

Comment: @MatthewUnderwood: please update the question with the requested information. In general, respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Comment: ... `var_export` and `var_dump` are more useful than `print_r`; the former produces valid PHP code (useful for answerers to test) and the latter shows data types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match_all("/:(\w+)/", $string, $matches);
```

By doing this, all your elements that are after a : will be in $matches[1] sub-array.  I'm assuming you want to handle SQL statements with multiple named parameters.  So for example:

```
SELECT user_name FROM test WHERE user_name = :user_name and last_name = :last_name
```

Will result in $matches being:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) ":user_name"
    [1]=>
    string(10) ":last_name"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(9) "user_name"
    [1]=>
    string(9) "last_name"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your question so it's better for others to see result.But answer:
`preg_split` returns an array, and what you're seeking is an element of array:

```
<?php  $arr = preg_split('/[:]/', $query, 0); 

   print($arr[1]);

 ?>
```

this returns `user_name` as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use, [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match) for this

```
$query = "SELECT user_name FROM test WHERE user_name = :user_name";
preg_match('/:(\w+)/', $query, $matches);
echo $matches[1]; //gives your user_name
```